# Selenium how to get all elements inside a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to get all the elements inside a selenium `WebElement`, for example:

```
<div>
    <element>
        <header>header</header>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </element>
    <element>
        <p>Another Paragraph</p>
    </element>

</div>
```

I want to get a list of all the elements inside  including child elements, like so...

1. div
2. element
3. header
4. paragraph
5. element
6. paragraph

So I've tried this

`element.findElements(By.xpath("*"))`

but this would return only

1. element
2. element

So then I tried a recursive method to get all of the childs

```
private static ArrayList<WebElement> getAllElements(WebElement element, ArrayList<WebElement> ret) {
    ret.add(element);
    List<WebElement> childs = element.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
    for(WebElement e: childs)
        getAllElements(e,ret);
    return ret;
}
private static List<WebElement> getAllElements(WebElement element) {
   return getAllElements(element,new ArrayList<WebElement>());
}
```

But querying `findElements()` takes too long

I'm thinking there must be a `xpath` way, but I can't seem to find it

Comment: find.Elements(By.xpath("//div") will return all elements for that div

Comment: @ratsstack this will return all the `div`s of the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `WebElement.findElements` method to get list of all the elements inside element.

For above HTML, to get list of all elements present inside div, we can use below code:

```
// Get webelement for div tag
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"));

// Below will return a list of all elements inside element
List<WebElement> webEleList = element.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));

//For above given HTML it will print 5. As there are 5 elements inside div
System.out.println(webEleList.size());
```